# Rich ReactNative TextInput

Tags: react-native

Any way to create a "rich" TextInput in React Native? Maybe not a full blown wysiwyg, but maybe just change the text color of various pieces of text; like the @mention feature on Twitter or Facebook.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? I'm trying to do something similar (only more like a rich-text editor with **bolding**, _italics_, etc).

Comment: No. I never did find a solution. In my case I was trying to style @mentions with some kind of container or background color in the input. Ended up just removing that text from the input and putting it in another view above. Wasn't ideal, but it worked.

Comment: @chapeljuice solution found - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49082641/1828637

Comment: @nicholas its too late to ask.. but can you show a solution if possible

Comment: @SagarChavada Noitidart's solution below worked perfectly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52342466/5895830.. plz take a look on this one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solution is that you can use `<Text>` elements as children in a `<TextInput>` like this:

```
<TextInput>
    whoa no way <Text style={{color:'red'}}>rawr</Text>
</TextInput>
```

Comment: Whoa! You can do that? I'm going to have to give that a try.

Comment: @nicholas hahaha yeah man my mind was blown too. I've been doing RN for a year and I had no idea!

Comment: This work for Android, do someone had fine how to do this on IOS?

Comment: @Angel - dang now way this doesnt work on iOS? Did you test?

Comment: Yes, I did a test, it don't worked. If you try working in a expo snack /snack.expo.io the text will not appear, if you work on a CRNA project it will throw a warning

Comment: Darn that totally stinks. I was hoping it would work. :(

Comment: @Angel try wrapping instead of child `<Text>` use `<View>` with background color. It seems in iOS we can have nested `View`. If this works, then nest a `<Text>` inside this view with the styling you want, let me know if that works.

Comment: I have never think like this.

Comment: @Noitidart can you plz help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52342466/implement-mention-in-textinput  i am not able apply view on TextInput

Comment: @SagarChavada this solution will only work in Android. I don't know how to nest `<Text>` in iOS `<TextInput>` yet.

Comment: What a nice and clean solution. haha. Thankyou

Answer (score 12):

This question was asked a while ago but I think my answer can help other people looking for how to color the @mention part of a string. I am not sure if the way I did it is clean or the "react" way but here is how I did it: 
I take the inputed string and split it with an empty space as the separator. I then loop through the array and if the current item matches the pattern of @mention/@user, it is replaced with the Text tag with the styles applied; else return the item. At the end, I render inputText array (contains strings and jsx elements)inside the TextInput element. Hope this helps!

```
render() {
let inputText = this.state.content;
if (inputText){
  inputText = inputText.split(/(\s)/g).map((item, i) => {
    if (/@[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g.test(item)){
      return <Text key={i} style={{color: 'green'}}>{item}</Text>;
    } 
    return item;
  })
return <TextInput>{inputText}</TextInput>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: you have my respect! Thank you.

Comment: Is nested <Text> within <TextInput> supported on iOS?

Comment: I am not sure if it's still supported. However it worked for me like a year ago. You could try

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the [TokenizedTextExample](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) from the react-native docs. I think that'll get you close to what you're looking to do. The relevant code follows:

```js
class TokenizedTextExample extends React.Component {
  state: any;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: 'Hello #World'};
  }
  render() {

    //define delimiter
    let delimiter = /\s+/;

    //split string
    let _text = this.state.text;
    let token, index, parts = [];
    while (_text) {
      delimiter.lastIndex = 0;
      token = delimiter.exec(_text);
      if (token === null) {
        break;
      }
      index = token.index;
      if (token[0].length === 0) {
        index = 1;
      }
      parts.push(_text.substr(0, index));
      parts.push(token[0]);
      index = index + token[0].length;
      _text = _text.slice(index);
    }
    parts.push(_text);

    //highlight hashtags
    parts = parts.map((text) => {
      if (/^#/.test(text)) {
        return <Text key={text} style={styles.hashtag}>{text}</Text>;
      } else {
        return text;
      }
    });

    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          multiline={true}
          style={styles.multiline}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState({text});
          }}>
          <Text>{parts}</Text>
        </TextInput>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the reply as suggested.

Comment: Whoa I never knew you could put `<Text>` as children in a `<TextInput>`! This is super cool! This example doesn't seem to exist anymore on the RN docs, do you have any place I can find about this?

Comment: set <Text> as a children of <TextInput> don't work on IOS. Other tip: if you set the value  property of <TextInput> it will give you a error because you can't have a <Text> children and value property in the same <TextInput>

Answer (score 5):

You will have to use **regex** in order to achieve that behaviour. Someone has already created package for that have a look at [react-native-parsed-text](https://github.com/taskrabbit/react-native-parsed-text)

This library allows you to parse a text and extract parts using a RegExp or predefined patterns. Currently there are 3 predefined types: url, phone and email.

Example from their github

```
<ParsedText
          style={styles.text}
          parse={
            [
              {type: 'url',                       style: styles.url, onPress: this.handleUrlPress},
              {type: 'phone',                     style: styles.phone, onPress: this.handlePhonePress},
              {type: 'email',                     style: styles.email, onPress: this.handleEmailPress},
              {pattern: /Bob|David/,              style: styles.name, onPress: this.handleNamePress},
              {pattern: /\[(@[^:]+):([^\]]+)\]/i, style: styles.username, onPress: this.handleNamePress, renderText: this.renderText},
              {pattern: /42/,                     style: styles.magicNumber},
              {pattern: /#(\w+)/,                 style: styles.hashTag},
            ]
          }
        >
          Hello this is an example of the ParsedText, links like http://www.google.com or http://www.facebook.com are clickable and phone number 444-555-6666 can call too.
          But you can also do more with this package, for example Bob will change style and David too. foo@gmail.com
          And the magic number is 42!
          #react #react-native
</ParsedText>
```

Comment: That will help match patterns typed in the text, but the question was how might I then change the style of that text in the text input? Like the way facebook will highlight your mention's name with a blue background in the text field itself.

Comment: You can do it by putting `ParsedText` inside `TextInput` component and removing the props `value` of the `TextInput`, after that the child of `ParsedText` just have to be set to the value you set in the `TextInput`, like that:

```
<TextInput
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}>
    <ParsedText
       ....props>
       {this.state.text}
    </ParsedText>
</TextInput>
```

Comment: @JérémyMagrin I think `ParsedText` only works on Android, is this true?

Comment: @Nakib, hi there after 6 years :), i wonder how to apply to functional componet